# Adding temporary rows to a custom table

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action, dtf

I fell in love with `CustomTable` to build data-driven WiX installs.  I had a custom action that I needed to execute on a dozen or so objects during an installation.  Instead of having 12 `<Custom Action=`... entries in the `InstallExecute` sequence, I put all the appropriate stuff into a CustomTable and process via a loop inside a single CustomAction.

Now I want to leverage the functionality that WiX provides, such as `XmlFile` in conjunction with CustomTables.  For example, I have a bunch of .config/xml files to process during the install; instead of having a million `<XmlFile`... elements in the Wix source I would like to add rows to the `XmlFile` table directly.  Similar situation for configuring IIS where there are many WebApplication and WebVirtualDirs that I need to configure.

It looks like this can be done by inserting "temporary rows" into the appropriate table-- ie `XmlFile` or `IIsWebVirtualDir`.  But I can't seem to find any examples of how to do this with DTF or otherwise.

Bob Arnson alluded to the fact that this is possible in an old post on [joyofsetup](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2007/07/01/semi-custom-actions/) that I came upon, unfortunately I can't find any other references to how to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the installer database functions from a custom action. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368250(v=VS.85).aspx

For details and some examples please see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372021(v=VS.85).aspx